# Marking up Yahoo Weather (JSON) using php/jquery/html

Tags: php, jquery, json, yahoo-api

I have used a YQL query to return a JSON object from Yahoo Weather. However i'm not sure how to markup this object.

The returning JSON object is:

```
{
   "query":{
      "count":3,
      "created":"2017-12-01T20:28:57Z",
      "lang":"en-GB",
      "results":{
         "channel":[
            {
               "item":{
                  "forecast":{
                     "code":"28",
                     "date":"01 Dec 2017",
                     "day":"Fri",
                     "high":"3",
                     "low":"0",
                     "text":"Mostly Cloudy"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "item":{
                  "forecast":{
                     "code":"26",
                     "date":"02 Dec 2017",
                     "day":"Sat",
                     "high":"7",
                     "low":"1",
                     "text":"Cloudy"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "item":{
                  "forecast":{
                     "code":"26",
                     "date":"03 Dec 2017",
                     "day":"Sun",
                     "high":"8",
                     "low":"6",
                     "text":"Cloudy"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I can see that the hierarchy is:
query > results > channel[item > forecast > WEATHER DATA]

Any help or pointers to webpages / documentation is appreciated. I am also happy to provide any further information if required.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "markup this object"?

Comment: This is the kind of thing i'm after, note that this is from a different data source (since I don't know where to start with weather).

Comment: I don't have enough characters to include all of the code extract

Comment: `$.getJSON("getposts.php" , function(data) { $.each(data, function (index, entry) { $('#content').append('<p><strong>' + entry.name + '</strong></p>');`

Comment: That doesn't really answer Daniel's question, what do you mean by "markup" in your question? What are you trying to do? What problems are you running into?

Comment: I'm trying to format the JSON object into HTML tags (typically what you would expect to see when viewing a weather widget) e.g. display the date from the items as <h3>, and the temperature as a <p>

Comment: Ok, the main thing here is knowing how to access the data. In JavaScript, it would be as simple as doing something like `query.results.channel[index].item.forecast.code` to get the forecast code of a specific channel. (based on the JSON you provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json_decode` to easily parse JSON:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%2C%20units.temperature%2C%20item.forecast%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22Stoke%20On%20Trent%2C%20United%20Kindgdom%22)%20and%20u%20%3D%20%22C%22%20limit%203%20%7C%20sort(field%3D%22item.forecast.date%22%2C%20descending%3D%22false%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys");

$data = json_decode($json);

echo $data->query->count; // Will echo out the value of count, 3 in this case
```

Comment: How would I change the line `$json = '{"query":....` to something dynamic, rather than hard coded data? The source of the data is: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%2C%20units.temperature%2C%20item.forecast%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22Stoke%20On%20Trent%2C%20United%20Kindgdom%22)%20and%20u%20%3D%20%22C%22%20limit%203%20%7C%20sort(field%3D%22item.forecast.date%22%2C%20descending%3D%22false%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

Comment: I've updated the answer, but `file_get_contents` works fine for getting data from an API endpoint when authorization isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks for that, this works nice. Instead of displaying the count value, how may I display "date" (e.g. for channel[0])

Comment: I've solved this I think: echo $data->query->results->channel[1]->item->forecast->day;

Comment: Correct, except that you probably want to loop over the channels to get each item in there. Just using index 1 would only give you data for Saturday.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the JSON retrieval and display using AJAX?

Comment: Absolutely, you can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for a pure JavaScript implementation or use JQuery if you'd rather go that route. AJAX is front-end though, so you wouldn't be doing anything in PHP.